# When a Creature dies, does the Enchantment Creature attached to that Creature go in the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

Or can you place that Enchantment Creature as a Creature on the battlefield after the Creature it was attached to dies?

Comment: Are you asking about cards with the Bestow mechanic from Theros block, on cards like [Cavern Lampad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373726)?

Comment: My friend bought the Born of the Gods -deck (which seems to be a part of Theros), but he is asking of GENERALLY Enchantment Creatures.
So I don't know.

Comment: Not all enchantment creatures *can* be attached as auras, only those with bestow. (You'll get much more useful answers if you can make your questions specific.)

Comment: At the moment, the one and only Enchantment Creature outside Theros block is Lucent Liminid, which cannot enchant anything. Here's a Gatherer search for all Enchantment Creatures outside Theros (which will redirect to the only card meeting those criteria): http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&type=+%5B%22Enchantment%22%5D+%5B%22Creature%22%5D&set=+!%5B%22Theros%22%5D+!%5B%22Born%20of%20the%20Gods%22%5D+!%5B%22Journey%20into%20Nyx%22%5D

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the situation. Normally, when a creature dies (goes to the graveyard) or gets exiled, all attached enchantments are moved to the graveyard as well.

> 704.5n If an Aura is attached to an illegal object or player, or is not attached to an object or player, 
>   that Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard.

Unless you have a bestow enchantment:

> 702.102e If an Aura with bestow is attached to an illegal object or player, it becomes unattached. This is an exception to rule 704.5n.

Of course, that has also has its exceptions, for example when a player casts [End Hostilities](http://magiccards.info/ktk/en/8.html), then all creatures, and its attached permanents are destroyed.