# Does a bestow creature falling off trigger Impact Tremors?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast a [Reckless Imp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reckless%20Imp) for its Dash cost and Bestow a [Nyxborn Rollicker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nyxborn%20Rollicker) on it, will the Rollicker still become a creature and trigger [Impact Tremors](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Impact%20Tremors) upon the Imp returning to my hand?

Comment: This had two "unclear what you're asking votes but it sure looks like a clear dup to me; edited to clarify. (Dash isn't really important here, it's just what happens to be the reason the bestowed creature falls off in this example.)

Comment: @Jefromi It looks to me like there are 2 separate questions being asked. 1) Will the dash mechanic cause a bestowed aura to become a creature? And 2) Will a bestowed aura becoming a creature trigger ETB effects? Only the second is a duplicate; the first is unanswered.

Comment: With impact tremors in play, cast reckless imp for dash cost, attach nyxborn rollicker for bestow cost, swing, return reckless imp to hand as specified and then "nyxborn rollicker" returns to field correct? Then that again triggers "impact tremors correct?

Comment: The Nyxborn Rollicker never leaves the battlefield, it just changes into a creature

Comment: @GendoIkari I didn't think there was any doubt about the fact that the bestowed creature ends up as a creature, but I suppose we can answer that!

Comment: So does nyxborn rollicker have to be cast for bestow to trigger "grim guardian" or does being an "enchantment creature" alone allow for trigger?

Comment: @Gendolkari The first question you extracted is a duplicate of [When a Creature dies, does the Enchantment Creature attached to that Creature go in the graveyard?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/20834/6692) The second you extracted is a duplicate of [If a permanent transforms into a creature, has it entered the battlefield?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11009/6692)

Comment: @Bryan If you have a new question please don't ask it in comments, ask it as a new question.